# Shell script: parse blank spaces correctly on command

Tags: shell, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on a script to fetch movies (mp4 and mkv files) over ssh with rsync from my server to my local computer, but I'm getting an error with folders that have spaces on the full path. The script is shown below (not much implemented yet!)

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd=(`find /home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/ -type f | grep .mp4`)

for i in "${cmd[@]}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

and the output I'm getting is this

```
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Nightwish.Rock.in.Rio.2015.720p.WEBRip-NRD.mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Limitless.S01E09.HDTV.x264-LOL[ettv]/limitless.109.hdtv-lol[ettv].mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/The.Last.Man.On.Earth.S02E07.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/The.Last.Man.On.Earth.S02E07.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv].mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Mom.S03E03.HDTV.x264-LOL[ettv]/mom.303.hdtv-lol[ettv].mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Family.Guy.S14E06.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/Family.Guy.S14E06.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv].mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Ant-Man.2015.720p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H264-RARBG/RARBG.com.mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Heroes.Reborn.S01E10.HDTV.x264-FUM[ettv]/Heroes.Reborn.S01E10.INTERNAL.HDTV.x264-FUM[ettv].mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/The.Middle.S07E08.HDTV.x264-LOL[ettv]/the.middle.708.hdtv-lol[ettv].mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Fargo.S02E06.INTERNAL.HDTV.x264-BATV[ettv]/Fargo.S02E06.INTERNAL.HDTV.x264-BATV[ettv].mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/Family.Guy.S14E05.HDTV.x264-FLEET[rarbg]/Family.Guy.S14E05.HDTV.x264-FLEET.mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/The
Man
in
the
High
Castle
S01E02
Sunrise
x264
poke/The_Man_in_the_High_Castle_S01E02_Sunrise_x264_poke.mp4
/home/pi/Transmission_Downloads/The.Walking.Dead.S06E06.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv]/The.Walking.Dead.S06E06.HDTV.x264-KILLERS[ettv].mp4
```

How do I prevent these line breaks from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does adding these lines before and after your script resolve the issue?

```
BKPIFS=$IFS
IFS='
' # note this is a newline character after the first quote so IFS is set to a newline
... your little script
IFS=$BKPIFS
```

If this does, the problem is that IFS (Internal Field Separator) by default contains whitespace causing streams including it to be split along whitespace boundaries. Hence, setting your IFS to newline explicitly after backing it up (BKPIFS), resolves conflicts with whitespace

Comment: It worked, thanks! Can you explain what is this $IFS? BKPIFS I'm guessing is "backup IFS", but what IFS means? nl means nil/null?

Comment: Cool - just updated my answer - would you mind accepting my answer?